# Instancing Frame class

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp

I'm writing C#/XAML/UWP application and I'm wondering about instancing of frame control (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame). I don't use caching, just standard scenario where each navigation creates a new instance of the specific Page subclass requested, and disposes the previous page instance. Each Page instance has Frame member, and navigation to another page is accomplished by:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(RequestedPage));
```

Can I assume, that for everypage **this.Frame** is the same object as "global variable" **Window.Current.Content** ? In what cases this assumption is not true?

Comment: I believe your assumption is correct, and it should not change unless you manually change it yourself.

Comment: Windows.Current.Content doesn't even have to be a Frame. It can be a SplitView for example, and that SplitView can hold a Frame. Also, you could even have multiple frames with their own kind of logic and pages in stack. So, if you just used the default, out of the box setup, it should be the same thing. If not, you have to be careful.

Comment: Look at the Cortana Voice Command sample in the [Microsoft git samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples). It contains a NavigationService and [NavigationHelper](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand/cs/AdventureWorks/Common/NavigationHelper.cs) that will be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

Frame is a content control which supports the page navigation.

Page is a UserControl, this.Frame indicated which frame the page instance was contained.

You can assign any UI Element (e.g. Text Block) to Windows.Current.Content property to make the UI element show on the current window.

By default, the app will assign a rootFrame instance to Window.Current.Content. So it is not a “global variable”.

About the cache of the Frame, you can check the document [NavigationCacheMode enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationcachemode).

Comment: By saying "global variable" I meant that Window.Current.Content is available in the whole scope of the application.